# Cause of misaligned patio doors

Tags: doors

I have a problem with a set of patio french doors that I can no longer lock
Upon examining them I found they are misaligned as can be seen in the below photos.

The doors are fully shut but there is a gap between the two doors as can be seen in the photos which prevents them from being flush

[image]
[image]
[image]

The gap is 1/8" at the top and increases to 3/8" at the bottom

Any ideas as to what is causing the misalignment and what must be done to correct the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a lot of sense that there's a gap the entire height of the door. What's preventing it from making contact?

As for the twist, one of two things is likely the culprit:

1. One or both of the doors is warped, due to excessive moisture and/or prolonged sun exposure. If that's the case, you'll probably just need to use extra force until it dries out. If it doesn't relax, you may need to replace the doors.
2. The wall has shifted, or the door frame has shifted in the wall. You'll need to apply some carpentry-foo and reset the door so that it's plumb, level, and square.

A close examination of all gaps and corners will reveal which is the problem. Post more photos if you like.